# accessing properties without object name and property name?

Tags: c#

Usually If I Need Accces Class properties , Than I Used To Write objectname.properties name(tempRecord) , But How Come Here It Work's Without Writing objectname.properties name

Usually If I Need Accces Class properties , Than I Used To Write objectname.properties name(tempRecord) , But How Come Here It Work's Without Writing objectname.properties name

```
 class TempRecord 
  {

 private float[] temps = new float[10] { 56.2F, 56.7F, 56.5F, 56.9F, 58.8F, 
                                        61.3F, 65.9F, 62.1F, 59.2F, 57.5F };
private int vps;

public float this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return temps[index];
    }

    set
    {
        temps[index] = value;
    }
}

public int mava
{
    set
    {
        vps = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return vps + vps;
    }

}
}

class MainClass
{
static void Main()
{
    TempRecord tempRecord = new TempRecord();
    tempRecord.mava = 4;
    // Usually If I Need Accces Class properties , Than I Used To Write objectname.properties name(tempRecord) , 
    //But How Come Here It Work's Without Writing objectname.properties name 
    tempRecord[3] = 58.3F; // Here Without Writing objectname.properties name
    tempRecord[5] = 60.1F; // here Without Writing objectname.properties name
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Element #{0} = {1}", i, tempRecord[i]);
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();

}
}
```

Comment: Becuase `TempRecord` has an indexed property. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx. Works in the same way you can access elements from a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [`Indexers (C#)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02(v=vs.120).aspx)

**Indexers** are a *syntactic convenience* that enable you to create a class, struct, or interface that client applications can access just as an array.

Indexers are most frequently implemented in types whose primary purpose is to encapsulate an internal collection or array. For example, suppose you have a class named TempRecord that represents the temperature in Farenheit as recorded at 10 different times during a 24 hour period.

The class contains an array named "temps" of type float to represent the temperatures, and a `DateTime` that represents the date the temperatures were recorded.

By implementing an indexer in this class, clients can access the temperatures in a `TempRecord` instance as `float temp = tr[4]` instead of as `float temp = tr.temps[4]`.

```
public int this[int index]    // Indexer declaration
{
    // get and set accessors
}
```

Comment: Is It Possible To Use Multiple Indexer In Same Class

Comment: Not in C#, but does not limit the `index type to integer`.

Comment: What Is The Use Of " this " Indexer Declaration

Comment: that is the syntax for Index Declaration ( ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: @KishoreSahas, that's not true.  I have declared multiple indexers in the same class.  The key is to make sure the signatures are different.  For instance, you can have an `int` indexer alongside a `string` indexer alongside an `int, int` indexer.